# How do I properly display a JSON response using angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, http

The following is a json response returned to angular js for error codes:

```
{"email":["The email field is required."],"username":["The username field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}
```

I am binding a variable in my controller to the html to display the result:

angular js:

```
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.errors = data;
});
```

html:

```
{{ errors }}
```

The html result of this is:

**{"email":["The email field is required."],"username":["The username field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}**

How do I get rid of the brackets, quotes, ect. so that I see just the data? I feel like this is a silly question, but I can't seem to find a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: What do you wanna display? You should write {{errors.email}} or better, create an array of errors and then display it with an ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify property which you want to display. And since you have an arrays in each property you can use `ng-repeat` to display data:

```
<p ng-repeat="error in errors.email">{{ error }}</p>

<p ng-repeat="error in errors.username">{{ error }}</p>

<p ng-repeat="error in errors.password">{{ error }}</p>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRYk2/)

Comment: That is a great idea :D. I will do that. But it still doesn't solve the issue of the displayed error message then being (for email): '["The email field is required."]'. How do I get it to show the data without the brackets and quotes?

Comment: @user2522373 I've added fiddle demo, there are no brackets, only the text. Could you check it again?

Comment: Whoa! You are right. It works great! Why does this work differently than using {{ error.email }} (aside from looping through)? Using just {{ error.email }} I still got the brackets and quotes.

Comment: @user2522373 I think because `error.email` contains an Array